# Selecting a value inside a combobox that shows from a datatable, and populate it as a INNER JOIN to the datagridview

Tags: sql, datagridview, combobox

Please have a look at my following code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; database=KnowledgeEssentials;Trusted_Connection= True;connection timeout=30");

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  distinct Problem FROM ProblemT ORDER BY Problem", conn);
    //ad.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  distinct Problem FROM ProblemT", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Problem"]);
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; database=KnowledgeEssentials;Trusted_Connection= True;connection timeout=30");
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProblemIDQA, Question FROM dbo.ProblemT INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionAnswer ON dbo.ProblemT.ProblemID = dbo.QuestionAnswer.ProblemIDQA", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    //comboBox1.DataSource = "SELECT  distinct Problem FROM ProblemT ORDER BY Problem";
```

Button 2 just populate the data to my combobox

I need Button 3 to have a selected item inside my combobox to populate to my datagridview as a INNER JOIN..... for example

I choose a problem inside the combobox
I press button 3
It populates the solution for the problem inside the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

I probably would have asked for a little bit of clarification before posting an answer, but apparently I don't have commenting functionality yet.

Some things that would probably help would be table schema definitions for your two tables, but I think I get the gist of what you are trying to do. Here is what I would do.

When populating your combobox, I would bind the datasource to the datatable instead of adding items like you are doing. (you'll have to add the ProblemID column to your query)

So instead of this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Problem"]);
}
```

do this

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Problem";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProblemID"; 
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Now in Button3_Click (I'd probably actually do this in comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged, but whatever) filter your query by the selected combobox value.

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
{
  int problemID = (int) comboBox1.SelectedValue;
  SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProblemIDQA, Question FROM dbo.ProblemT INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionAnswer ON dbo.ProblemT.ProblemID = dbo.QuestionAnswer.ProblemIDQA WHERE ProblemT.ProblemID = " + problemID.ToString(), conn);
...
```

No need to be setting your combobox datasource anymore in button3_Click. Also, if you wanted to be more efficient and if the size of the QuestionAnswer table is not that big I wouldn't do a database query in the button click, I'd load up the entire dataset in the form's load event for example so it is just loaded once. Then I'd use a DataView/BindingSource to do the actual filtering of the grid.